# How to set up Pinia getter in Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I am building a Pokemon filtered search app using Vue 3, Composition API, and Pinia. I am attempting to set up the app so that the fetched response from the Pokemon API is passed to a store (set up using Pinia) inside the fetchPokemon() function.

```
    const fetchPokemon = () => {
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0")
      .then((response) => {
        store.addPokemon(response.data.results)
      })
    }
```

After passing the response to the store, the updatePokemon() function uses filter and include methods to filter out and match Pokemon in the store with Pokemon in the user-input text field ("state.text"):

```
    const updatePokemon = () => {
      if(!state.text) {
        return []
      }
      return store.getState.pokemons.filter((pokemon) => 
        pokemon.name.includes(state.text)
      )
    }
```

When executing the app, I am getting the following error in the updatePokemon() function:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

I'm assuming this means the .includes() method for searching/filter cannot be used for this search. How should I go about handling the filter and include methods to match Pokemon in the store with the user-inputted Pokemon?

Here is the code:

Pinia Store

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const usePokemonStore = defineStore({
    id: 'store',
    state: () => ({
        pokemons: []
    }),
    getters: {
        getState(state) {
            return state
        }
    },
    actions: {
        addPokemon(name) {
            this.pokemons.push(name)
        }
    }
})
```

Component

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full flex justify-center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Pokemon here" 
    class="mt-10 p-2 border-blue-500 border-2" v-model="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-10 p-4 flex flex-wrap justify-center">
    <div class="ml-4 text-2x text-blue-400" 
    v-for="(pokemon, idx) in filteredPokemon" :key="idx">
      <router-link :to="`/about/${getPokemonId(pokemon.name)}`">
        {{ pokemon.name }} - with id {{ getPokemonId(pokemon.name) }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { reactive, toRefs, computed } from 'vue';
import { usePokemonStore } from '@/store';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  setup() {

    const store = usePokemonStore()

    const state = reactive({
      text: "",
      filteredPokemon: computed(()=> updatePokemon())
    })

    const updatePokemon = () => {
      if(!state.text) {
        return []
      }
      return store.getState.pokemons.filter((pokemon) => 
        pokemon.name.includes(state.text)
      )
    }

    const fetchPokemon = () => {
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0")
      .then((response) => {
        store.addPokemon(response.data.results)
      })
    }

    fetchPokemon()

    const getPokemonId = (item) => {
      console.log(item)
      return store.pokemons.findIndex((p) => p.name === item) + 1
    }

    return { ...toRefs(state), fetchPokemon, getPokemonId, updatePokemon, store }
  }
}
</script>
```

***UPDATED***

Store - with not action

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const usePokemonStore = defineStore({
    id: 'store',
    state: () => ({
        pokemons: []
    })
})
```

Component - with no store.addPokemon(...)

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full flex justify-center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Pokemon here" 
    class="mt-10 p-2 border-blue-500 border-2" v-model="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-10 p-4 flex flex-wrap justify-center">
    <div class="ml-4 text-2x text-blue-400" 
    v-for="(pokemon, idx) in filteredPokemon" :key="idx">
      <router-link :to="`/about/${getPokemonId(pokemon.name)}`">
        {{ pokemon.name }} - with id {{ getPokemonId(pokemon.name) }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { reactive, toRefs, computed } from 'vue';
import { usePokemonStore } from '@/store';

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  setup() {

    const store = usePokemonStore()

    const state = reactive({
      // pokemons: [],
      text: "",
      filteredPokemon: computed(()=> updatePokemon())
    })

    const updatePokemon = () => {
      if(!state.text) {
        return []
      }
      return store.pokemons.filter((pokemon) => 
        pokemon.name.includes(state.text)
      )
    }

    const fetchPokemon = () => {
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0")
      .then((response) => {
        store.pokemons = response.data.results
      })
    }

    fetchPokemon()

    const getPokemonId = (item) => {
      console.log(item)
      return store.pokemons.findIndex((p) => p.name === item) + 1
    }

    return { ...toRefs(state), fetchPokemon, getPokemonId, store }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `getState` at all.

You can use `usePokemonStore().pokemons` directly. The object returned by calling `usePokemonStore()` function includes:

- all state properties
- all actions
- all getters.

Here's how to get the filtered pokemon array, based on whether their name includes `state.text`:

```
setup() {
  const store = usePokemonStore();
  const state = reactive({
    text: "",
    filteredPokemons: computed(() => store.pokemons.filter(
      pokemon => pokemon.name.includes(state.text)
    ))
  });
  return {
    ...toRefs(state)
  }
}
```

Working example:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, toRefs, computed, onMounted } = Vue;
const { defineStore, createPinia } = Pinia;

const usePokemons = defineStore('pokemon', {
  state: () => ({ pokemons: [] })
});
const pinia = createPinia();
createApp({
  pinia,
  setup() {
    const store = usePokemons(pinia);
    const state = reactive({
      searchTerm: '',
      filteredPokemons: computed(() => store.pokemons.filter(
        pokemon => pokemon.name.includes(state.searchTerm)
      ))
    });
    onMounted(() => {
      fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => store.pokemons = r.results)
    });
    return {
      ...toRefs(state)
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.11/dist/pinia.iife.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchTerm">
  <div v-for="pokemon in filteredPokemons">
    {{ pokemon.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw storeToRefs is  a more convenient alternative to toRefs

Comment: @tao thanks. I removed ```getState``` and and then relocated the filter functionality directly to ```filteredPokemon``` in the reactive state, just like your snippet shows. However, I'm still getting the same error message about the .includes() method: ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')```

Comment: I've added a working demo to the answer. If that doesn't help, please create a [mcve] either here or on codesandbox.io (or similar), making sure it reproduces the bug you're having.

Comment: @JS_is, make sure the pokemons on the state is always an array. Initially, an empty array. And after you get the result, you assign the result.

Comment: @tao thanks! I removed the action in the store, as well as the addPokemons handler. I replaced addPokemons with ```store.pokemons = response.data.results```, which I believe is logically similar to ```store.pokemons = r.results``` in your snippet. This works. However, why is it necessary to pass the response results directly to ```store``` instead of pushing the response to the store with an ```action``` handler? In other words, why didn't it work to use an action handler to pass the response to store?

Comment: @JS_is, your `addPokemon` function adds strings to an array which is supposed to contain objects. Another thing: if your method sets the pokemons you should name it `setPokemons` not `addPokemons`. An `addPokemons` would look like this: `addPokemons(pokemons) { this.pokemons.push(...pokemons) }`. A `setPokemons` would look like this: `setPokemons(pokemons) { this.pokemons = pokemons }`. In both cases, the `pokemons` would be `{name: string; url: string }[]`.

Comment: To answer your question *"why is it necessary to pass the response directly to the store"*. It's not! You don't have to assign vs push. Assign replaces the entire array whereas push adds new items. Both work. But you need to make sure all members of the array have the same structure, at all times.